How do I access ipv4 sites from an ipv6 only vps
I bought an ipv6-only VPS because it's cheaper. I need to download some packages from mix deps.get but it fails, presumably because it has no ipv6 support.
My laptop can access both ipv4 and ipv6, so maybe I can use that to pipe the connection through. I tried using squid but without success. I only need it for a short time to get the required packages.

In theory that would be possible – set up a GRE (ip6gre) or WireGuard tunnel between the two systems, define an IPv4 default route on the server that goes through the tunnel (and from there through your laptop), and set up IPv4 NAT on the laptop. Pretty much the same as in the "set up your own VPN" tutorials except with the laptop as the server.
Check whether your hosting company offers either a regular NAT gateway (gives your VPS a private IPv4 address) or a NAT64/DNS64 gateway (makes IPv4 sites appear to your VPS as if they were IPv6). Either might still cost less than a dedicated IPv4 address.
